# LibGDX Box2DLights throws error on render

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, box2dlights

I am trying to get a Box2D PointLight to render on the screen, but upon rendering, it throws an exception. I have revised the API and the Box2D User Manual, as well as watched videos on the topic, but have yet to find a solution to my problem. Here is my code and the error.

```
package com.mygdx.test;

import box2dLight.PointLight;
import box2dLight.RayHandler;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;

public class Test extends ApplicationAdapter {
    /** the camera **/
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    RayHandler rayHandler;
    World world;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(48, 32);
        camera.update();
        world = new World(new Vector2(0, -10), true);
        rayHandler = new RayHandler(world);
        new PointLight(rayHandler, 32);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        world.step(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 8, 3);
        rayHandler.setCombinedMatrix(camera.combined);
        rayHandler.updateAndRender();
    }
```

And the error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FrameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture()Lcom/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture;
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:127)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FrameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture()Lcom/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture;
at box2dLight.LightMap.gaussianBlur(LightMap.java:76)
at box2dLight.LightMap.render(LightMap.java:37)
at box2dLight.RayHandler.render(RayHandler.java:328)
at box2dLight.RayHandler.updateAndRender(RayHandler.java:262)
at com.mygdx.test.Test.render(Test.java:33)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:215)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with a newly generated libgdx project, however updating the box2dlights version from 1.3 to 1.4 solved this error for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this method?

```
new PointLight(rayHandler, RAYS_NUM, new Color(1,1,1,1), lightDistance, x, y);
```

I have also noticed, you should do

```
world.step();
```

at the end of the *render()* method. Probably wont fix the problem, but i just noticed

Comment: I've tried using new Color(1,1,1,1), as well as Color.WHITE, though I still get a similar issue. Thanks for the recommendation of moving the world.step() method, makes a lot more sense at the end.